# Creating functions

Tags: python

Q: Write a function safe(n) that takes a non-negative integer n as input where n has at most 2 digits. The function determines if n is a safe number. A number is not safe if it contains a 9 as a digit, or if it can be divided by 9. The function should test if n is safe and return a string stating the result of the test, either “The number is safe”, or “The number is not safe”.( solve the questions below without loops, if and other branching statements, lists) 
So far I have:

```
def safe(n):
0<n<100
n%9!=0 
return 'The number is safe'
return 'The number is not safe'
```

I know this is wrong/ incomplete but I'm not sure how to do this?

Comment: Did you try opening the book and reading it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check for three different conditions:

```
def safe(n):
    not_divisible = n % 9 != 0
    not_9x = n // 10 != 9
    not_x9 = n % 10 != 9

    return not_divisible and not_9x and not_x9
```

To return a string without using an `if` statement, you can use a ternary operator:

```
def safe(n):
    not_divisible = n % 9 != 0
    not_9x = n // 10 != 9
    not_x9 = n % 10 != 9

    is_safe = not_divisible and not_9x and not_x9

    return 'The number is safe' if is_safe else 'The number is not safe'
```

Arguably, this still uses branching, so you can perhaps be clever:

```
def safe(n):
    not_divisible = n % 9 != 0
    not_9x = n // 10 != 9
    not_x9 = n % 10 != 9

    is_safe = not_divisible and not_9x and not_x9

    lookup = ['The number is not safe', 'The number is safe']
    return lookup[int(is_safe)]
```

Which is of course ridiculous, but then, so are the instructions.

**EDIT:** That solution uses lists, which are disallowed. Here's one with a dictionary:

```
def safe(n):
    not_divisible = n % 9 != 0
    not_9x = n // 10 != 9
    not_x9 = n % 10 != 9

    is_safe = not_divisible and not_9x and not_x9

    lookup = {
        False: 'The number is not safe',
        True: 'The number is safe'
    }

    return lookup[is_safe]
```

Comment: The instructions say no lists :D

Comment: @mentalita This is starting to sound more like a code golfing challenge than a homework problem. Maybe use a dictionary, I guess? ¯\\_(ツ)\_/¯

Comment: Definitely, agreed :)

Comment: what does not_9x and not_x9 stand for?

Comment: @H.G. `doesnt_start_with_9` and `doesnt_end_with_9`

Answer (score 0):

```
def safe(n):
    if n>0 and n<100:
        if n%9==0 or '9' in str(n):
            print('The number is not safe')
        else:
            print('The number is safe')
    else: 
        print('Not acceptable number')
```